# Using pivot on datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have the following table:

```
Date,Type
2012-01-25 13:48:00.000,1
2012-01-25 13:49:00.000,2
2012-01-26 13:48:00.000,1
2012-01-26 13:49:00.000,2
```

I tried the pivot function to get this layout:

```
1,2
2012-01-25 13:48:00.000,2012-01-25 13:49:00.000
2012-01-26 13:48:00.000,2012-01-26 13:49:00.000
```

I'm not sure if it's even possible to use the pivot function, because I have to use an aggregate function in pivot, right? Is it possible to use pivot or should i use an self join?

Best regards
Stefan

EDIT:

This is my pivot statement:

```
SELECT 
  [1],
  [2]

  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      [Date],
      [Type]

      FROM
        [Test]
  ) AS SourceTable
  PIVOT
  (
    SUM([Date]) FOR [Type] IN ([1],[2])
  ) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: You should add the pivot you tried.

Comment: change the `SUM` to `MAX`, and check once

Comment: That works, but when i have a second row in my table it won't be in the results.

Comment: You might want to provide sample data that match your scenario (e.g. "a second row2 in your table)...

Comment: @Lmu92 I added more sample data so that you know what i want to achieve. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with the classic Cross-Tab approach together with ROW_NUMBER to have "something" to group by:

```
;
WITH cte as
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER By Data) as pos, 
    * 
    FROM -- use your table name instead of the VALUES construct
    (VALUES
    ('2012-01-25 13:48:00.000' ,1),
    ('2012-01-25 13:49:00.000',2),
    ('2012-01-26 13:48:00.000',1),
    ('2012-01-26 13:49:00.000',2)) x(Data,Type)
)
SELECT 
MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN Data ELSE NULL END) AS [1],
MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 2 THEN Data ELSE NULL END) AS [2]
FROM cte 
GROUP BY pos
```